# How to make kotlin operator a Composable with parameters having default value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make Kotlin's `invoke` operator a `@Composable`, everything works fine, until I add a parameter to it, which should have a default value. See the code below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{
            Button()
        }
    }
}

object Button{
    @Composable
    operator fun invoke(text: String = "SomeText"){
        println(text) // prints: null
    }
}
```

When the operator is not annotated as `@Composable` the output is `SomeText`, as it should be.

Is this some error in Jetpack Compose, or am I missing something?

The behavior is the same on the latest stable Compose v 1.1.1 and on 1.2.0-beta01. Kotlin 1.6.21

Comment: Such basic reproducible issues should be [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) to the maintainers.

Comment: Yes, you probably should report that indeed, but anyway, out of curiosity, what difference exactly do you think it makes to make the invoke method a `@Composable`? When you call the invoke on a `@Composable`, it just executes it the same way while also having the property of being able to run only in a Composable scope. Now, if that's what you required, why not just annotate the `fun` itself like normal Composables? On the other hand, if you're trying to make a regular function and trying to contain a Composable in it in the hopes of using it in non-Composable scopes, I don't think it's simple

Comment: You'll require an under the hood knowledge of how Close is built. Also, I don't think it will be possible, since they would have built this thing from the ground up keeping this rule in mind.

Comment: @MARSK What I'm trying to achieve is a way to clean up the namespace, so that not all Composables are available as a top-level function. The general idea is to group all flavors of let's say Buttons (Primary, Secondary, Tertiary) to be Composables declared as a function of object Button. But I would like to be able to use also this Button object as a default Button (let it be Primary) in a Compose way, so just by using it as it would be a function, thus `invoke()` operator. I would have Button.Primary(), Button.Secondary() and Button() which would be an "alias" for Button.Primary().

Comment: Sir, THAT is the info you need to put in the question. That's your use-case. Use-cases are generally good to be mentioned since they help people suggest better approaches if they have one. It also helps you avoid bad and potentially buggy methods of achieving something because if we see that, we would know that is is not good for the particular use-case. So, always consider posting the use-case along.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info provided in the comments, I decided to answer:

I'll maybe think of something better, but off the top of my head, this is what you can do for now

```
enum class ButtonType {
 Primary,
 Secondary,
 Tertiary
}
```

Return the correct type of Button

```
@Composable
fun MasterButton(type: ButtonType) {
 when(type) {
  primary -> PrimaryButton()
  secondary -> SecondaryButton()
  else -> TertiaryButton() // Must provide an 'else' branch
 }
}
```

This will do the job for you.

CORRECT APPROACH I:

I just got the correct one the moment I started typing the first approach.

```
@Composable
fun ( @Composable () -> Unit ).Primary(...) {
 PrimaryButton()
}
```

Make copies for every other button.

**STRONG NOTICE**: This is a RIDICULOUS way of "cleaning" up the code. Nobody should ever use anything remotely resembling this ever, but since that is just what the question is about, this is how you go about doing it. Know that this will attach an extension function called `Primary(...)` to every single `@Composable` function, and that cannot change. You can't apply it to select Composable(s) only, since this is basically just an extension function that I have applied on a general `labmda`, since 'extension functions for extension functions' are not something that exist as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take this as your question (even though it is in the comments) and try to answer the way I achieve this.

> What I'm trying to achieve is a way to clean up the namespace, so that
> not all Composables are available as a top-level function. The general
> idea is to group all flavors of let's say Buttons (Primary, Secondary,
> Tertiary) to be Composables declared as a function of object Button.
> But I would like to be able to use also this Button object as a
> default Button (let it be Primary) in a Compose way, so just by using
> it as it would be a function, thus invoke() operator. I would have
> Button.Primary(), Button.Secondary() and Button() which would be an
> "alias" for Button.Primary().

My implementation is quite simple,

1. Expose only one top-level Composable function to have a cleaner namespace.
2. Pass an argument that denotes the type of the required Composable, using a sealed class.

**Button Type**

```
sealed class MyIconButtonType(
    open val typeName: String,
) {
    data class Default(
        override val typeName: String = "default",
    ) : MyIconButtonType(
        typeName = typeName,
    )

    data class BorderIconButton(
        override val typeName: String = "border",
        // The variant specific attributes can be added here
        val borderWidth: Int,
    ) : MyIconButtonType(
        typeName = typeName,
    )
}
```

**Button** (The only composable exposed to other files)

```
@Composable
fun MyTestIconButton(
    onClickLabel: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    data: MyIconButtonType = MyIconButtonType.Default(),
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    when (data) {
        is MyIconButtonType.Default -> {
            // This composable should be private
            MyTestIconDefaultButton(
                // parameter as required
            )
        }
        is MyIconButtonType.BorderIconButton -> {
            // This composable should be private
            MyTestIconDefaultButton(
                // parameter as required, also make sure to pass variant specific attributes here
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// For default impl
MyTestIconButton(
    // default parameters
) {

}

// For specific variants
MyTestIconButton(
    // default parameters
    data = MyIconButtonType.BorderIconButton(
        borderWidth = 10,
    ),
) {

}
```

**Note:**

1. Data class requires at least one attribute. Use object if no attributes like the `typeName` are required.

Like this,

```
sealed class MyIconButtonType {
    object Default : MyIconButtonType()
    data class BorderIconButton(
        val borderWidth: Int,
    ) : MyIconButtonType()
}
```

Kotlin concepts that are used for reference,

1. [Sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html), [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) and [objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html)
2. [`when` statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression)
3. [Visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#class-members)